# I am getting 2 errors, CS8803, and C20266

Tags: c#, console-application

While programming a console application to calculate circumference and when I compiled my code I got two console errors (look above) here is my code

```
Console.Title = "Constant";
enum Days { Sat, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu , Fri};
const double pi = 4159265358979;
var daystype = typeof(DayOfWeek);
Console.WriteLine("Pi Type" + pi.GetType());
Console.WriteLine("Circumfrence" + (pi * 3));
```

Comment: please include the error messages, I mean they are right there in front of you

Comment: you cannot put all c# code inside this simplified main mechanism. (enum in this case). You will have to create a 'classic' static main app

Comment: As a C# developer with ~10 years of professional experience, I have no idea what CS8803 and CS20266 are. I'm sure I'd recognise them instantly if the error messages were included instead. By only including the error code, you add another step which we have to perform to help you: we have to search to find out what the error codes mean. Also, some error messages include names of specific types that caused the error message, so only including the error code in such situations might make it impossible to give a targeted answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can not put enums inside of local function . Your app structure should  be

```
public class Program
{

 enum Days { Sat, Sun, Mon, Tue, Wed, Thu, Fri };

    static void Main()
    {
        Console.Title = "Constant";
        const double pi = 4159265358979;
        var daystype = typeof(DayOfWeek);
        Console.WriteLine("Pi Type" + pi.GetType());
        Console.WriteLine("Circumfrence" + (pi * 3));
    }
}
```